# Automatic conversion from picture commands to tikz-pgf

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I'm trying to modify an old document with a bunch of images created using the `picture/pict2e` environment.
The problem is that I need to improve these images, but adding some new features in those old environments sometimes require a lot of work, while in TikZ would be just a couple of parameters.

So, the question: is there a way to automatically convert `picture` images into TikZ/`pgf` images ?

Comment: The simple answer here, 'No', seems a bit short!

Comment: @JosephWright: It's still good to know. Thanks for the information :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just to summarize Joseph's NO and add a but. If you are willing to spend a lot longer than simply translating the code you had the misfortune to inherit, here is a methodology.

First you need to write gobbling macros for all the pict2e macros, including also a whole lot of macros from the original picture environment as well. How you do that? For example to gobble the `\picture` macro you can use:

```
\def\picture(#1,#2)(#3,#4){%
  \def\storepiconevar{#1}
  \def\storepictwovar{#2}
  \def\storepictthreevar{#3}
  \def\storepicfourvar{#4}
  % starts the tikZ environment
  \tikzpicture
}
  % ends the tikZ environment
\def\endpicture{\endtikzpicture}
```

For some you maybe able to develop translation macros between the two such as the simplistic example below (not showing any actual calculations for simplicity).

```
 \def\line(#1,#2)#3{\draw(#2,#1)--(#1,#1);}
```

Trying it out in a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\def\picture(#1,#2)(#3,#4){%
  \def\storepiconevar{#1}
  \def\storepictwovar{#2}
  \def\storepictthreevar{#3}
  \def\storepicfourvar{#4}
  % starts the tikZ environment
  \tikzpicture
}
\def\endpicture{\endtikzpicture}
\def\line(#1,#2)#3{\draw(#2,#1)--(#1,#1);}
\begin{document}
\unitlength=0.5cm
\begin{picture}(0,0)(2,0)
  \line(1,0){2}
\end{picture}
\end{document}
```

Worth a try if you want to learn both `pict2e` and `tikZ` very well. Let us know if you come up with a package.

Comment: I'm not so skilled in LaTeX to start writing something that can be turn into a package, but this is definitely applicable in my case, because the picture I need to improve are really simple (just a bunch of lines, vectors, rectangles) and my need is just to add some dashing, colors, arrow styles and so on. Hence, I will give it a try, thanks a lot ! :)

Comment: @digEmAll I think it is also a very good way to learn both `TikZ` and `pic2e`. I am not using `TikZ` very often and keep looking the commands up:)